# Is it possible to view 'default storeview' dropdown attribute values in product Admin Grid?

Tags: magento2, attributes, admin-panel, store-view

I've got a dropdown attribute as is in M2.3.4 admin

Admin => 1
Default Store view => 'Text for id 1'

Admin => 2
Default Store view => 'Text for id 2'

But when I go to product section, even when changing scope to 'Default Store view', Admin values are shown in the dropdown. So it's not very easy to create a product. Any solution for this ?

Thank you.

Comment: You are facing this while creating new product or editing?

Comment: Hello, both cases. It's not normal behavior ?